# Is it possible to degrade from Internet Explorer 7 to Internet Explorer 6 for debugging purposes?

Tags: internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I'm having Internet Explorer 6 problems on one of my sites, and I really wish I had it installed instead of Internet Explorer 7.  Is there a quick way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running IE6, IE7, and IE8 on the same machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574463/running-ie6-ie7-and-ie8-on-the-same-machine)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Multiple IE](http://tredosoft.com/Multiple_IE):

> It is possible to run Internet Explorer in standalone mode without having to over-write previous versions thanks to [Joe Maddalone](http://web.archive.org/web/20090101200355/http://archivist.incutio.com/viewlist/css-discuss/33150) who came up with a way of achieving that in November 2003. Basically, Internet Explorer is run by exploiting a known workaround to DLL hell - which was introduced in Windows 2000 and later versions - called DLL redirection.
>
> [Manfred Staudinger](http://web.archive.org/web/20090101200355/http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/multiIE.html) perfected the standalone versions by adding IE version numbers to the title bar of the standalone browser window. Moreover, by removing the "IE" key in the registry subkey `[HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Version Vector]` Internet Explore defaulted to respecting conditional comments based on the version number prebuilt in the program.
>
> It is not difficult to follow the instructions and get any version of IE running in standalone along side other versions. Most of you probably know of [evolt's archive of Internet Explorer](http://web.archive.org/web/20090101200355/http://browsers.evolt.org/?ie/32bit/standalone) which has them readily packaged in ZIP files. Now suppose you want to download them all. An installer that would conveniently automate the whole process would be great. Thanks to [this comment](http://web.archive.org/web/20090101200355/http://tredosoft.com/node/25#comment-512) for the idea.
>
> So I made an installer which contains IE3 IE4.01 IE5 IE5.5 and IE6...

Comment: This is a good choice but using the VM method is much more reliable, MultipleIE doesn't give a true legacy experience.

Comment: Agreed with prior comment.  i've had issues esp. with ie6, and been unable to reproduce bygs via multiple ies

Comment: No one can reproduce IE6 bugs (they are hardest to reproduce bugs in history, and brought quite a few people close to madness), better go with a VM ;)

Comment: Just a word of warning: Although I do love the multiple IEs software, it doesn't seem to affect IE6 in a positive way allowing for some functions to work while they don't work when IE6 is installed without IE7 installed.

Comment: The one drawback with Multiple IE is that it doesn't support conditional comments. So if you're using these to include an IE6-specific stylesheet, you'll be stuck.

Answer (score 16):

Download [Microsoft VirtualPC](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/virtualpc/default.mspx). Then download any of the files in [Internet Explorer Application Compatibility VPC Image](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=21EABB90-958F-4B64-B5F1-73D0A413C8EF&displaylang=en). The second download contains four VHD (virtual hard drive) files which have:

- XP SP2

  - IE 7
- XP SP3

  - IE 6, IE 8 Beta 2
- Vista SP1

  - IE 7

Answer (score 4):

Download [Virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/downloads/virtualpc/default.mspx) and set up a bunch of them for testing with various browsers/OS's.  Once set up, this makes it trivial to test on IE6,7 and 8, various Firefox flavours, Konqueror, Opera, Safari, etc...

See [Samuel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421945/possible-to-degrade-from-ie7-to-ie6-for-debuggin-purposes#421988) for a helpful VPC image in getting this started:

Comment: What about licensing for the Windows images? My solution works for Windows without worrying about licensing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421945/possible-to-degrade-from-ie7-to-ie6-for-debuggin-purposes#421988

Comment: Sure - I elided the details of setting up or downloading the VPCs, since that will vary based on your requirements, but your link to the IEAC image is certainly a great time-saver.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend always testing your sites using [BrowserShots](http://browsershots.org/).  You can see how your site looks across multiple browsers, with multiple versions, on multiple operating systems.  You can do something like 50 tests a day on their free service.

Answer (score 1):

Also check out [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage), which gives you 5.5, 6, 7, 8b2 in one app.

Answer (score 1):

[Litmus](http://litmusapp.com/) is another BrowserShots-esque service.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me: [Multiple IE](http://tredosoft.com/Multiple_IE)

Edit: looks like the minute it took me to find the URL was enough for 3 people to beat me to it..wow

Answer (score -1):

[IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) is pretty good, compare IE5.5/IE6/IE7/IE8 side by side.